# Why does this code print out a 4?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why this program uses floats but I get a 4 outputted. 
I thought floats only output decimals. Any help would be appreciated, I have been starring at this code for a while now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

using namespace std;

float avg( int Count, ... )
{
    va_list Numbers;
    va_start(Numbers, Count);

    int Sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
        Sum += va_arg(Numbers, int);

    va_end(Numbers);
    return (Sum/Count);
}

int main()
{
    float Average = avg(10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);

    cout << Average;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside from whatever problem you're having `Sum += va_arg(Numbers, int);` is wrong. You're reinterpreting a `float` as `int` and that's not going to work at all.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: I think it's meant to return the average of 10 integers.

Answer (score 2):

Your code truncates `45/10` to `4` since `45/10` is an integer division.

If you want to preserve the decimal portion, change the expression slightly to make it a floating point division.

```
return (1.0*Sum/Count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Sum is an int; when you are returning, you are dividing Sum by Count, which truncates it to the decimal portion, and *then* converting it to a float to return it.

To get the right answer, you should first convert it to float, then divide and return it: e.g.

```
return ((float) Sum) / Count;
```

Or, you could declare Sum as a float, and that would get rid of this problem.